# Two itemized lists side by side

Tags: vertical-alignment, itemize

I'm new with LaTeX.

Hi would like to have two itemized lists set side by side like this:

```
Grandes nacelles :              Petites nacelles :  
    * Nacelle A318 PW               * Nacelle SAAB2000
    * Inverseur A320 CFM            * Inverseur DC8
    * Inverseur A340 CFM            * Inverseur CF34-8
    * Nacelle A340 TRENT            * Inverseur BR710
    * Inverseur A330 TRENT          * Nacelle F7X
    * Nacelles A380 TRENT900            
    * Nacelles A380 GP7200
```

Could someone tell me how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried ? To me, simply using `multicol` or 2 `minipage` would do the trick.

Answer (score 14):

One solution with multicol

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
Grandes nacelles :
\begin{itemize}
\item Nacelle A318 PW
\item Inverseur A320 CFM
\item Inverseur A340 CFM
\item Nacelle A340 TRENT
\item Inverseur A330 TRENT
\item Nacelles A380 TRENT900
\item Nacelles A380 GP7200
\end{itemize}

\columnbreak

Petites nacelles :
\begin{itemize}
\item Nacelle SAAB2000
\item Inverseur DC8
\item Inverseur CF34-8
\item Inverseur BR710
\item Nacelle F7X
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I one of the lists is stretched (latex is trying to make both lists the same height by adding space between items) add  `\raggedcolumns` after `\begin{multicols}{2}`

Answer (score 7):

You can use `varwidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{varwidth}[t]{.5\textwidth}
Grand nacelles :
\begin{itemize}
\item Nacelle A318 PW
\item Inverseur A320 CFM
\item Inverseur A340 CFM
\item Nacelle A340 TRENT
\item Inverseur A330 TRENT
\item Nacelles A380 TRENT900
\item Nacelles A380 GP7200
\end{itemize}
\end{varwidth}% <---- Don't forget this %
\hspace{4em}% <---- Don't forget this %
\begin{varwidth}[t]{.5\textwidth}
Petites nacelles :
\begin{itemize}
\item Nacelle SAAB2000
\item Inverseur DC8
\item Inverseur CF34-8
\item Inverseur BR710
\item Nacelle F7X
\end{itemize}
\end{varwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just an FYI, this didn't work in my beamer slides. The multicol solution does work.

Comment: This solution worked for me in my article document and multicol solution didn't work.

Comment: @egreg why is the '%' trailing \end{varwidth} and \hspace necessary?  I've seen it in a few solutions, but no descriptions.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using the `pdfcolparallel` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcolparallel}
\begin{document}

\begin{Parallel}{0.45\textwidth}{0.45\textwidth}
\ParallelLText{
    \textbf{Grandes nacelles}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Nacelle
        \item etc
        \item etc
        \item etc
    \end{itemize}
}
\ParallelRText{
    \textbf{Petites nacelles}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Nacelle
        \item etc
        \item etc
        \item etc
    \end{itemize}
    }
\ParallelPar
\end{Parallel}

\end{document}
```