# How to put two items perfectly aligned LaTeX itemize

Tags: tables, itemize, layout, bullets

I have a large `Tex` file, simplified as below:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newcommand{\Item}[1]{
    \item\small{
        \begin{justify}
            {#1 \vspace{-2pt}}
        \end{justify}
    }
}


\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet, leftmargin=0.38in]
    \Item{Item one}
    \Item{Item two}
    \Item{Item three}
    \Item{Item four}
    \Item{Item five}
\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}

\end{document}
```

#### Which gives me:

[image: this]

#### How can I achieve something similar to the picture below?

[image]

Consider that the items are put into a **table** with 3 rows and two columns, while the items are **aligned to the left**, and the table **takes the whole space available** as `\textwidth`.

### Edit:

I ended up using `varwidth` package. it simply defines columns with selected width, and you are free to put any kind of item inside each. Read [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233825/241836).

Comment: Either with the `tasks` environment (homonymous package) or with two  itemize environments in two side-by-side minipages.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Item one \switchcolumn
    \item Item two \switchcolumn
    \item Item three \switchcolumn
    \item Item four \switchcolumn
    \item Item five
\end{itemize}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newcommand{\Item}[1]{
    \item\small{
        \begin{justify}
            {#1 \vspace{-2pt}}
        \end{justify}
    }
}
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet, leftmargin=0.38in]
    \Item{Item one}\switchcolumn
    \Item{Item two}\switchcolumn
    \Item{Item three}\switchcolumn
    \Item{Item four}\switchcolumn
    \Item{Item five}\switchcolumn
\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I couldn't get the same output as yours, it might be because of other packages that I'm using which they're not present in yours. Did you get the same result with my other packages included?

Comment: @Tabaraei: I just updated my answer with a code closer to the one you showd in your question.

Answer (score 1):

As I said, the simplest would be to load `tasks`, which uses a syntax quite close to the `enumitem` syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}[style=itemize](2)
    \task Item one
    \task Item two
    \task Item three
    \task Item four
    \task Item five
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Added* If you have to use the `\item` command, you can load tthe `shortlst` package, and use the `shortitemize` environment, with this code:

*Preamble*:

```
\usepackage{shortlst} 
\AtBeginEnvironment{shortitemize}{\setlength{\shortitemwidth}{0.4 \linewidth}}
```

*Document body*:

```
\begin{shortitemize}
    \item Item one
    \item Item two
    \item Item three
    \item Item four
    \item Item five
\end{shortitemize}
```

[image]

Comment: I should only use \item commands as it's shown in the question. couldn't you please provide an answer with side-by-side minipages as you mentioned in the comments?

Comment: I can, but the items one, two, three will be vertically aligned on the left, and the other items vertically aligned on the right.

Comment: @Tabaraei: I've added an example code with the `shortitemize` environment, from `shortlst`, which does use `\item`.